# Get most commonly occurring value for each user id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with `userIds` and product categories `prod`. I want to get a table of unique `userIds` and associated most occurring product categories `prod`. In other words, I want to know what item categorys each customer is buying the most. How can I achieve this in PL/SQL or Oracle SQL?

```
|userId|prod|
|------|----|
|123544|cars|
|123544|cars|
|123544|dogs|
|123544|cats|
|987689|bats|
|987689|cats|
```

I have already seen SO questions for getting the most common value of a column, but how do I get the most common value for each unique `userId`?

Comment: It's neccesary plsql? can be sql?

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?  For example: in your sample data, Userid 987689 .. do you want bats, or cats? both are most occurring (ie once).

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Just SQL is fine as long as it is Oracle compliant. All ties should be included, which means that the userId will be repeated on multiple rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, prod, prod_cnt FROM (
    SELECT user_id, prod, prod_cnt
         , RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY prod_cnt DESC ) AS rn
      FROM (
        SELECT user_id, prod, COUNT(*) AS prod_cnt
          FROM mytable
         GROUP BY user_id, prod
    )
) WHERE rn = 1;
```

In the innermost subquery I am getting the `COUNT` of each product by user. Then I rank them using the analytic (window) function `RANK()`. Then I simply select all of those where the `RANK` is equal to 1. Using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` ensures that ties will be returned.

Answer (score 3):

You should use just SQL to solve this .. if you really need it in pl/sql, just imbed this query within plsql ..

**(setup)**

```
  drop table yourtable;
  create table yourtable (
     userID   number,
     prod     varchar2(10)
     )
  /

  insert into yourtable values ( 123544, 'cars' );
  insert into yourtable values ( 123544, 'cars' );
  insert into yourtable values ( 123544, 'dogs' );
  insert into yourtable values ( 123544, 'cats' );
  insert into yourtable values ( 987689, 'bats' );
  insert into yourtable values ( 987689, 'cats' );

  commit;
```

**-- assuming ties are not broken, this logic returns both ties**

```
  with w_grp as (
        select userID, prod, count(*) over ( partition by userID, prod ) rgrp
          from yourtable
        ),
     w_rnk as (
        select userID, prod, rgrp,
               rank() over (partition by userID order by rgrp desc) rnk,
          from w_grp
        )
  select distinct userID, prod
    from w_rnk
   where rnk = 1
  /

      USERID PROD
  ---------- ----------
      987689 bats
      987689 cats
      123544 cars
```

**-- assuming you just want 1 .. this will return 1 random one if they are tied.** (ie this time it pulled 987689 bats, next time it might pull 987689 cats. It will always return 123544 cars, however, since there is no tie for that one.

```
  with w_grp as (
        select userID, prod, count(*) over ( partition by userID, prod ) rgrp
          from yourtable
        ),
     w_rnk as (
        select userID, prod, rgrp,
               row_number() over (partition by userID order by rgrp desc) rnum
          from w_grp
        )
  select userID, prod, rnum
    from w_rnk
   where rnum = 1
  /

      USERID PROD             RNUM
  ---------- ---------- ----------
      123544 cars                1
      987689 bats                1
```

[edit] Cleaned up unused rank/row_number from functions to avoid confusion [/edit]

Comment: Just wondering, can't you get rid of the `DISTINCT` in the code? And why calculate row_number() when not using it.

Comment: I used the same query for both ;) (ie was doing both in same query .. so yeah, if you use the RANK option, remove row_number, if you use the row-number option, remove rank.  As for DISTINCT .. try removing it ... the RANK will pull duplicates for 123544 cars - since there's 2 rows, both with count(2) .. (it's the way the analytics work).  So to get the results you want, you only need 1 of those rows, not both (ie distinct)

Comment: you're right. When i was typing my answer I had used a group by in the first query. Got rid of the duplicates right there :)

Comment: It would make more sense to use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` in `W_GRP`, I think ... that would eliminate the duplicates that you see from using analytics.

Comment: @David: In this specific sample, perhaps .. I have a habit of using analytics like this because I handle a lot of requests for the "original row" .. based on whatever criteria ;) So that tends to be knee-jerk pattern for me lately.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I chose to go with @DavidFaber's answer because it appears to be more concise. Specifically, there is one less `partition` statement that I have to write. It was a tough call. Still, I upvote this answer.